# Strtok with whitespace in C

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
char inputp1[32], inputp2[32];

char input[32];

printf("-> ");
scanf("%s", input);

strcpy(inputp1, strtok(input , " ,.-"));
strcpy(inputp2, strtok(NULL, " ,.-"));
printf("%s\n", inputp1);
printf("%s\n", inputp2);

}
```

With this I can enter:

```
-> 10.10 // my input
10
10
```

And its the same with 10-10 and 10,10 but using 10 10 does this:

```
-> 10 10
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any ideas?

Note: if this is a dupe just tell me and if it fixes this ill delete this post.
Thanks.

Comment: `scanf` with `%s` reads till a whitespace.

Comment: Check the return value of functions that can return null pointers, just in case they _do_ return a null pointer.  Then you can avoid your code crashing.

Comment: @mch Your comment is incomplete.  `"%s"` reads optional leading white-space (ignores them) and _then_ scans non-white-space up to, but not including a subsequent white-space.

Comment: See also [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read till first white space than use `scanf("%s", input);` this will read character until first space is read.

Use `fgets(input, size, stdin)` to read entire line.

You can also use something like `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` This will read until first newline character and also will flush the newline character so it will not cause any problem. The `[]` is called scanset. You can read about it [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html)

Despite temptation, you should [never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters `gets()` will read, and because `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use. It has been used to break computer security. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Yeah scanf() can get an buffer overflow from what I know

Comment: Yes I also don't prefer this `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` but it is still not deprecated like gets

Comment: Okay thanks. Then I can use `if ((strlen(input)>0) && (input[strlen (input) - 1] == '\n'))
         input[strlen (input) - 1] = '\0';` to remove the newline

Comment: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` reads nothing into `name` if the first character is `'\n'`, leaving `name` unchanged and the `'\n'` still in `stdin`.  `fgets()` is much better.  Also it is not buffer limited.

Comment: @John Dow `input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;` is a simple 1-liner to remove the potential `'\n'`.  Your method is good, yet [no need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729970/2410359) to call `strlen()` 3x.

Comment: 1) using the "%s" format specifier with `scanf()` enables the user to overflow the input buffer.  When using '%s" always include a `max length` modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, so the user cannot overflow the buffer.  Overflowing the input buffer results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event. 2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful. I.E. the call to `scanf()` should be: `if ( 1 != scanf( "%31s", input ) { // then handle error due to scanf failing }`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", input)` reads till first whitespace only. To read the entire line, you can use `fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)` or `scanf(" %[^\n]", input);`

Comment: Disagree with `scanf(" %[^\n]", input);`.  It is as good as suggesting `gets(input)` and that is not good.